# What is this feature called where vscode deletes up to the closing bracket?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am just trying to figure out how he did this.

https://gifyu.com/image/SLb2s

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: It is definitely not Delete all right cos then the bracket would have been deleted too.

Comment: The cursor style suggests to me they are using a vim plug and using "cib" in command mode.